# C: Why I am given similar things over multiple mallocs?

Tags: c, malloc

I wrote a demo on dynamic 2D arrays:

```c
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

# define getarray2d(obj, dst) int (* dst)[obj->w] = (int (*)[obj->w])&(obj->data)

typedef struct _myarray {
    int *data;
    size_t h;
    size_t w;
} myarray;

myarray * mallocarray2d(size_t h, size_t w) {
    myarray *arr = (myarray *)malloc(sizeof(myarray));
    int *data = (int *)malloc(h * w * sizeof(int));
    arr->data = data;
    arr->h = h; arr->w = w;
}

void freearray2d(myarray *arr) {
    free(arr->data); free(arr);
}

void printarray2d(myarray *arr) {
    getarray2d(arr, array2d);
    size_t h = arr->h; size_t w = arr->w; size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            printf("%12d  ", array2d[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    myarray *arr = mallocarray2d(3, 4);
    printarray2d(arr);
    freearray2d(arr);
}
```

As expected, output is a "random" array:

```
F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
  -695987216           555             3             0
           4             0   -1651400550     268491609
  -695968000           555    -695991984           555
```

But things became interesting after I ran it for multiple times:

```
F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
   630939408           398     630915408           398
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
 -1688379632           607   -1688403632           607
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
  1305501456           532    1305477456           532
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
   906452752           352     906428752           352
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
 -1575002352           473   -1575026352           473
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
  1594253072           518    1594229072           518
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
   444751632           400     444727632           400
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153
```

Elements at pos (0, 1) (2, 1) (2, 3) are always equal, and elements at pos (0, 2) (0, 3) (1, 0) (1, 1) always remain 3 0 4 0

Is there a specific reason for this?

EDIT: I corrected my faults:

```c
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

# define getarray2d(obj, dst) int (* dst)[obj->w] = (int (*)[obj->w])(obj->data)

typedef struct _myarray {
    void *data;
    size_t h;
    size_t w;
} myarray;

myarray * mallocarray2d(size_t h, size_t w) {
    myarray *arr = (myarray *)malloc(sizeof(myarray));
    void *data = malloc(h * w * sizeof(int));
    arr->data = data;
    arr->h = h; arr->w = w;
    return arr;
}

myarray * callocarray2d(size_t h, size_t w) {
    myarray *arr = (myarray *)malloc(sizeof(myarray));
    void *data = calloc(h * w, sizeof(int));
    arr->data = data;
    arr->h = h; arr->w = w;
    return arr;
}

void freearray2d(myarray *arr) {
    free(arr->data); free(arr);
}

void printarray2d(myarray *arr) {
    getarray2d(arr, array2d);
    size_t h = arr->h; size_t w = arr->w; size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            printf("%12d  ", array2d[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    myarray *arr = mallocarray2d(3, 4);
    printarray2d(arr);
    freearray2d(arr);
}
```

result:

```
F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
   630939408           398     630915408           398
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
 -1688379632           607   -1688403632           607
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
  1305501456           532    1305477456           532
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
   906452752           352     906428752           352
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
 -1575002352           473   -1575026352           473
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
  1594253072           518    1594229072           518
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153

F:\Users\23Xor\Desktop>a.exe
   444751632           400     444727632           400
  2037603443    1835365491    1666986547    1697539181
  1140876664    1702259058    1952531570     977485153
```

the last 8 elements even stops changing.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You're missing `return arr;` in `mallocarray2d`

Answer (score 0):

Since reading uninitialized data invokes undefined behavior, there is no satisfactory answer to your question.  The official answer is:  don't do that, it's not allowed by the rules of the C language, so the C language makes no guarantees about what will happen if you break the rules.  You might end up reading all-zeroes, or all-42's, or `0xDEADBEEF`, or your program might crash, or any other conceivable behavior might occur, because the resulting executable is not considered a valid C program.

At a practical level, you're printing out the values of whatever leftover garbage happened to be present in the area of RAM that `malloc(h * w * sizeof(int))` returned to you when you called it.  Why those values happened to be there (and not something different) is a function of how your C runtime's heap allocator works, combined with whatever the heap was being used for previously in your program's startup (e.g. before `main()` was called)... you could probably work out why they end up in that particular state, if you want to spend several days stepping through the source code of your C runtime with a debugger and a notepad.  It probably wouldn't be worth the effort, though.

Comment: "Since reading uninitialized data invokes undefined behavior" It does not in this case. The first paragraph of your answer is all wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40674888/584518.